# Hibernate Many-To-Many. Not saving

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have 2 Hibernate objects Category and Article which are related with a ManyToMany relationship. In DB: category, article and cat_art tables.

I use the following mapping

Category:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "cat_art", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "article_id") })
public List<Article> getArticles() {
    return articles;
}
```

Article:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "articles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public List<Category> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}
```

Test code:

```
    article.setTitle("test");
    article.setDescription("testtesttest");

    Category cat = categoryService.getCategoryById(1L);
    article.getCategories().add(cat);
    cat.getArticles().add(article);

    articleService.addArticle(article);
    categoryService.addCategory(cat);
```

- Hibernate: select category0_.id as id1_3_0_, category0_.title as title2_3_0_ from category category0_ where category0_.id=?
- Hibernate: select articles0_.category_id as category1_3_0_, articles0_.article_id as article_2_2_0_, article1_.id as id1_1_1_, article1_.account_id as account_5_1_1_, article1_.description as descript2_1_1_, article1_.time as time3_1_1_, article1_.title as title4_1_1_ from cat_art articles0_ inner join article article1_ on articles0_.article_id=article1_.id where articles0_.category_id=?
- Hibernate: insert into article (account_id, description, time, title) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

My problem is when I add a article to a category, no record is added to the association table cat_art. Where am i doing wrong? Thanks

Service layer example:

```
@Service("articleService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ArticleService {

private ArticleDAO articleDAO;

@Autowired
public ArticleService(ArticleDAO articleDAO) {
    this.articleDAO = articleDAO;
}

@Transactional
public void addArticle(Article article) {
    articleDAO.addArticle(article);
}
```

DAO example:

```
public class ArticleDAOImpl extends HibernateDAO implements ArticleDAO {

@Autowired
public ArticleDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super(sessionFactory);
}

@Override
public void addArticle(Article article) {
    getSession().save(article);
}
```

CategoryService and DAO are similar

Comment: Are you starting a transaction at some point? You must start a transaction and commit or rollback. It is not clear how you do that in your code. We need more details of your environment. Is this a standalone app, a JEE or Spring app, etc.?

Comment: It's Spring app. In service layer I have transaction annotation on each method etc. There is two transactions... first: `articleService.addArticle(article);` and second: `categoryService.addCategory(cat);`

Comment: I've added examples in my question.

Comment: Is your Spring context configured to process transaction annotations?

Comment: Spring context is ok. Transactional annotations are working.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you annotated your service class with both `@Service` and `@Repository`. You better mark your DAO as a `@Repository` and remove it from the service class.

Comment: `
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  
  Article article = new Article();
  Account account = new Account();
  account.setId(1L);
  article.setTitle("Lol");
 article.setDescription("LOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOO");
  article.setAccount(account);
  
  Category category = (Category) session.get(Category.class, 1L);
  article.getCategories().add(category);
  category.getArticles().add(article);
  session.saveOrUpdate(category);
  session.getTransaction().commit();
 }` This example correctly work. But when I use @Transactional my exmpl dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in tag in spring-servlet.xml - it was defined to scan the root package with all the web controller, repository classes, etc.

After changing it to make scanning of the package with web controllers only, the problem was gone.. I thank everyone for answers. And sorry for my bad English.